# How do I create a sublist in Wordpress's Wysiwyg with-out editting the HTML?

Tags: wordpress

The title says it all, I want to do this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

With out actually doing that.  How can I do this in the wysiwig?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use the **indentation icon** (the one pointing right) when the focus is on the line you want to become the first item of the sublist.

### In images:

[image: 1st step]

becomes:

[image: Result]

Comment: Funny how things that can be obvious to some people and completely not to others.  I tried hitting tab to get it to indent, but never thought to use the indent button :D

Comment: Yeah, I hate it when a rich-text editor doesn't catch my tabs and then just sends the focus somewhere else.

Comment: Genius! Perfect!